# Webmin time module and CentOS

Tags: centos, time

When I try to install webmin time module on my VPS running CentOS I get this error message:

> Failed to install standard module : Module time does not support this
>   operating system (CentOS Linux 5)

What should I do to have time and date configuration option in my Webmin?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are on a VPS (openVZ I presume), so time is controlled by your host, you can not change the date and/or time or run `ntp`.

I have no experience with webmin, but a quick google query learned me that you can disable the Time Module. You should probably do that.

Details: http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SystemTime